# Как вывести запросом много записей из БД по нескольким параметрам?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
def checkDBtest():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('orders.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    cur.execute("select * from items where iditem='"+("10")+"'")
    return cur.fetchall()
```

Так вывожу запись с `id` 10.

Можно ли как-то вывести сразу много записей. Например, у меня есть массив `[10, 20, 1,3]`, могу ли я вывести одним запросом (без цикла) сразу все эти строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях можно использовать параметризированные запросы и создавать их динамически:

```
ids = [10, 20, 1,3]
qry = "select * from items where iditem in ({})".format(",".join("?" * len(ids)))
cur.execute(qry, ids)
```

сгенерированный запрос:

```
In [180]: qry
Out[180]: 'select * from items where iditem in (?,?,?,?)'
```